# Issues to space <li> elements with pourcentage

Tags: html, css

I can't space these li elements of my footer with pourcentage on padding left... Otherwise, the inline-block I used don't work anymore...

I already tried to use % but then it stops to be inline...

Can you help me ?

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 99;
}

.footer ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 5%;
}

.footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer">

    <ul>
      <li>
        <div id="humidity">15%</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="temp">15°C</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="clock">15h15m15s</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="date" class="date">15.15.15</div>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1670 97" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<g>
 <path fill="#FE4A11" d="M1669,52.659V97H847.357H0V52.659l122.675-16.814l142.712,3.871c0,0,231.45-27.464,236.787-27.78
  c5.336-0.316,272.148,27.132,272.148,27.132l198.221-14.81l360.398,14.679l231.414-15.818L1669,52.659z"/>
 <path fill="#FE4A11" d="M1669,52.659V97H847.357H0V52.659l122.675-16.814l142.712,3.871c0,0,231.45-27.464,236.787-27.78
  c5.336-0.316,272.148,27.132,272.148,27.132l198.221-14.81l360.398,14.679l231.414-15.818L1669,52.659z"/>
</g>
</svg>

  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set `width: 100%;` on `ul` element.
I created a pen for what you want to achieve:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/darculadev/pen/YbjMyJ)

Answer (score 1):

add width:100% to the UL element

```css
footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;  
  z-index:99;
}

.footer ul{
    position:absolute;    
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
    list-style-type: none;
    bottom:15px;
    right: 5%;
    width:100%;
    }


.footer li {
   display: inline-block;  
    
    padding-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<div class="footer">

<ul>
    <li><div id="humidity">15%</div></li>
    <li><div id="temp">15°C</div></li>
    <li><div id="clock">15h15m15s</div></li>
    <li><div id="date" class="date">15.15.15</div></li>
  </ul>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1670 97" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<g>
    <path fill="#FE4A11" d="M1669,52.659V97H847.357H0V52.659l122.675-16.814l142.712,3.871c0,0,231.45-27.464,236.787-27.78
        c5.336-0.316,272.148,27.132,272.148,27.132l198.221-14.81l360.398,14.679l231.414-15.818L1669,52.659z"/>
    <path fill="#FE4A11" d="M1669,52.659V97H847.357H0V52.659l122.675-16.814l142.712,3.871c0,0,231.45-27.464,236.787-27.78
        c5.336-0.316,272.148,27.132,272.148,27.132l198.221-14.81l360.398,14.679l231.414-15.818L1669,52.659z"/>
</g>
</svg>

</div>
</footer>
```